# Background Blur div

Tags: html, css, background, adobe

Need help to create this background blur without blurring the text.
I have tried the css filter property, but couldn't make it look like this.
I'm not a CSS shark, so i hope someone can give me an easy solution :D

Adobe XD Background Blur:

[image]

Comment: Although it's an experimental technology, and although I'm almost an year late, you are definitely looking for [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter). I generally set it to `blur(15px)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided any code so this will help you.

You can make a div with blur background using `filter: blur(13px);` in css and the content can't be inside the blurred div, so we will use a sibling element instead like this

```css
body {
  background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.blur {
  background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: blur(13px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
}

.widget {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 57px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget center">
  
  <div class="blur"></div>
  
  <div class="text center">
    <h1 class="">I am blurred div</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want the div to be transparent with blur, not use an image. That's possible right? The blurred div is supposed to be a fixed nav.

Comment: Here it's not a blurred image used. What's happening is the same image is used on blurred div and then blurring the image using css

Comment: Could you look at my markup?http://mcniels.dk/mcniels.dk/index.html
i want the div with class "navigation" to be transparent with blur

Comment: Just add `<div class="blur"></div>` inside `<div class="navigation">` with the css and change height to 100% and give background image as the image yo are using for the body background. It will work

Comment: If you click at the link you can see that the div isn't transparent, it just looks like it. I want it to adapt to the content.
https://imgur.com/FQdm766

Comment: Take a look again at http://mcniels.dk/mcniels.dk/index.html
I just need the right "color" or blur like above.

Comment: @NicklasNielsJensen add opacity:0.5 and chek if it meet your requirements